# The Angular CLI currently requires npm version 6

Tags: angular-cli

I am using angular ng new command to create a application.

ng new angular-hello-world.

got below error.
npm version 7.5.1 detected.
The Angular CLI currently requires npm version 6.

Please install a compatible version to proceed (`npm install --global npm@6`).

any idea what it is ?  why need to install npm@6

Comment: There is an issue for that: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19957

Answer (score 4):

try this instead

```
npm install --global npm@6
```

Comment: This is actually the recommended solution until issues are solved in npm 7, as explained in https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19957

Answer (score 3):

Yo can solve this problem using the latest Node.js version compatible with npm 6: *Node.js 14.15.Z*

Use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) (Mac or Linux) or [nvm windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) (Windows only) to manage multiple Node.js versions in your computer.